# pyresttest - Unable to read body from a DELETE request

Tags: python, rest, pyresttest

Consider the following template which is used to delete an entity from DB.

```
- test:
    - group: "Basic Test"
    - name: "Delete 10.24.39.202"
    - url: "/v1/switch"
    - method: 'DELETE'
    - expected_status: [200]
    - body: '{"ip_address": "10.24.39.202"}'
    - headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ZGV2ZWw6WjNGSmVFTlliMUJvYlVSclVrOWhXRVp3ZDIwNFUzQktSekpzTjBnMGVYVT0=',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

This doesn't work and I get the following error while decoding the body:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stack/git/bwc/bwc/server/switch.py", line 1880, in delete
    request = json.loads(self.request.body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

From the changelogs, pyresttest supports body in delete request

```
1.6.0 Mon Oct 12 07:30:00 2015 -0400
BETA: support setting request body on all request types, if present
Allows (for example) DELETE methods that set a request body
Caveat: does not set length if 0
```

I am sure that I am using version 1.6.0. What could be the issue?

Comment: Yes I am sure that the error is from this test. Only this test failed and I have the logs with exception. Same request with curl works without any issues.

Comment: Question includes the stackrace now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an [honest to goodness bug](https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest/issues/162) in the test framework (PyRestTest), now fixed.  Root cause was that PyCurl wants to set up the DELETE with a body the same way as a POST request (size from the POSTFIELDSIZE), rather than like a PUT (INFIELDSIZE).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The bug is resolved and now I am able to read the body.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be sending a payload with a `DELETE` request.  From [RFC 7231 § 4.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5):

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

Even if pyresttest supports it, it's non-standard and the server / proxies in use may not support it.

Comment: The same request with curl works fine. The request handler expects body to be present.

Comment: Sure – as the specification says, this is non-standard and inconsistently supported.  So some software will work with it, and some won't.  If the request handler expects the body to be present, then you should re-examine your API design, because it can't be supported reliably.